# code with map method in swift 1.2 does not work in swift 2, what to change?

Tags: swift, dictionary, swift2

I am new in programming and I was advised to use the following code to make a new array with three letter elements from an array having one letter elements. It is working perfectly with swift 1.2, but not with swift 2.  Complains are  -  "map is unavailable: call the map() method on the sequence". What should I change?

```
let tripletsDnaSequence = map(stride(from: 0, to: newDnaSequence.count, by:   3)) 
{
String(newDnaSequence[$0..<advance($0, 3, newDnaSequence.count)])
}
```

Comment: "call the map() method on the sequence" That's pretty clear. Do you understand the difference between a global function and a method?

Comment: No, I am ready to hear !

Comment: Okay, well, the implication, if you don't know that, is that you don't know _anything_ about Swift, so I would suggest you start right at the beginning of my book: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch01.html

Comment: Matt's book looks great. But in a nutshell, Swift 1.2 used map(something) vs. Swift 2 uses something.map().

Comment: Ok, thanks for the link!

Comment: Oh, by the way Xcode has a feature that will convert your Swift 1.2 code to 2.0.

Comment: I did such a conversion, but Xcode7 left this question about map.

Comment: Thanks @MirekE, your comment is exactly answering my question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Call the `map` method" is pretty clear; there is no more concise or clearer way to say it, really. You must now talk like this:

```
stride(from: 0, to: newDnaSequence.count, by: 3).map { /* ... */ }
```

If you don't know what a method is, you are going to have great difficulty reading, writing, and understanding Swift.